# make browser transform without effecting one specified element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developing a webpage zoom-out and zoom-in option for my website, I use browser `Transform` ([transform CSS propertise](http://www.css3files.com/transform/)) to scale my web page to 90% of the original view

```
In Chrome-   document.body.style.webkitTransform = 'scale(' + value + ')';
```

**value is 0.9 for 90%.**

but my webpage has **one html element** which I do not want to scale, I want to keep it in the same original view/size..

any possible way of doing this?

note: I tried putting that html element after the `</body>` tag but still scales it to 90%...

Comment: scale the special element *up* by `111.111%`.

Comment: Wrap your content in a div, except the one you don't want to scale then scale the div.

Comment: Is it just the scale you want to counteract, or also the effect on the translation that occurs?

Comment: @Lee - that element has .swf (flash) contents which are created using java scripts so no effect from re scaling it.. :( 
thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: @Musa - yep it works, I just created a new div for elements I need to scale except that element.. :) thank you very much..

Comment: @Phrogz - I just wanted to scale the whole view of my webpage to 90% but eventually I realized that it is not necessary to scale one element... btw I found the solution ! Thank you very much for the comment..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scale the body down to 90%, and then scale the special element *back up* to its original size:

```
document.body.style.webkitTransform = 'scale(0.9)';
specialElement.style.webkitTransform = 'scale(1.111111)';
```